# jQuery - Animate backgroundSize with data-attributes

Tags: jquery, this, custom-data-attribute

I want to animate backgroundSize to the amount from the `data`-attributes.

```
<div class="polloption" data-percent="36" data-id="123" data-poll="12" style="background: url(img/danger.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

And the jQuery-Part:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var percent = $(this).attr('data-percent');
        $('.polloption').text(percent);   
        $('.polloption').animate(
            {
                backgroundSize: percent + '%',
            }, 1000);       
    });
```

Nothing happens on document ready.
But if I write `backgroundSize: '36%'` manually - it works.

How can I get the `data-percent` from the current `.polloption`?

Comment: [With `data()`.](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
var percent = $(this).attr('data-percent');
```

change such a line to:

```
$('.polloption').each(function (idx, ele) {
    var percent = $(ele).attr('data-percent');
    $(ele).text(percent);
    $(ele).animate({
        backgroundSize: percent + '%',
    }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: This will work only with one value for all `.polloption` 
But I have multiple `.polloption`

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much!